# JQuery UI Dialog: Called in focus event but element not focused after closing dialog

Tags: focus, jquery-ui-dialog

see Title. I'm showing a Jquery UI modal dialog to the user in the focus event of an Input element. When the dialog is closed I want that input to be focused. This does not happen. It seems that calling the dialog in the focus event prevents the focus from happening.

The dialog is shown when the user must select from multiple values. These values are fetched via ajax with a parameter from a different input field. If there is only 1 value returned (or none) the dialog does not appear and the input element is correctly focused. So the issue clearly is due to the dialog.

```
$("#myInput").focus(function() {
    //... get data, show dialog if multiple values in result
    $("#dialog").dialog( "open" );
}); 

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close")}},
        height: 120,
        width: 185,
        position: [285,200],
        modal: true,
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $('#myInput').val($("#select").val()); // Select element in dialog
        }
});
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just focus again the input when the dialog closes:

```
$('#myInput').val($("#select").val()).focus(); 

 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close")}},
    height: 120,
    width: 185,
    position: [285,200],
    modal: true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('#myInput').val($("#select").val()).focus(); 
    }
});
```